# Operator overloading assignment operator

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class shared_ptr
{
    public:
    int *pointer;
    public:
    shared_ptr()
    {
        pointer = new int;
    }
    ~shared_ptr()
    {
        delete pointer;
    }
    int operator* ();
    int* operator= (shared_ptr&);
};

int shared_ptr:: operator* ()
{
    return *(this->pointer);
}

int* shared_ptr:: operator= (shared_ptr& temp)
{
    return (temp.pointer);
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr s1;
    *(s1.pointer) = 10;
    cout << *s1 << endl;
    int *k;
    k = s1;         //error
    cout << *k << endl;
}
```

I am trying to create something like smart pointer.

I am getting the following error while trying to overload operator = .

prog.cpp:39:9: error: cannot convert ‘shared_ptr’ to ‘int*’ in assignment for the k = s1 assignment line.
What am I missing here?

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* A cast?

Comment: Can I have implementation where I dont need cast? I mean using this like pointers

Comment: to allocate memory then copy will be nice idea I think, otherwise you may victim of segfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did provide `operator =` for

```
shared_ptr = shared_ptr
```

case(very strange operator btw). But you are trying to use

```
int* = shared_ptr
```

You need either getter or cast-operator in shared_ptr to make it possible

Actually you may use it like

```
shared_ptr s1, s2;
...
int* k = (s1 = s2);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/YU2LaU)

But it's absolutely ugly

Answer (score 1):

Your `Operator =` returns `int*` but you don't have a constructor that gets `int*`, add:

```
shared_ptr(int *other)
{
    pointer = new int(*other);
}
```